# Python - Retrieving an element from a tuple from a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

I am a beginner in Python and am struggling on retrieving an element out of a tuple from a list. What I am trying to do is to get the value of a fruit and multiply it by the quantity needed. An example below will show you what I mean. I can not figure out how to get the second element in the tuple.

```
##Cost of [('apples', 2.0), ('pears', 3.0), ('limes', 4.0)] is 12.25


fruitPrices = {'apples':2.00, 'oranges': 1.50, 'pears': 1.75,'limes':0.75,   
               'strawberries':1.00}

def buyLotsOfFruit(orderList):
##    orderList: List of (fruit, numPounds) tuples        
## Returns cost of order

totalCost = 0.0 
for fruit,price in fruitPrices.items():
  if fruit not in fruitPrices:
    print 'not here!'
  else:
    totalCost = totalCost +fruitPrices[fruitPrices.index(fruit)].key() * price            
return totalCost
```

It is mostly in my else statement that I can not get it working. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The indentation for the body of `buyLotsOfFruit` is off right?

Comment: Maybe, sorry it is when I pasted it into here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you looping over the dictionary? Loop over your list instead, and add to `totalCost` accordingly.

```
for fruit, n in orderList:
    if fruit in fruitPrices:
        totalCost += fruitPrices[fruit] * n
    else:
        print fruit, 'not here!'
```

---

You can simplify all this and do something like

```
sum(fruitPrices.get(fruit, 0) * n for fruit, n in orderList)
```

Note that `fruitPrices.get(fruit, 0)` will return `fruitPrices[fruit]` if `fruit` is in `fruitPrices` and `0` otherwise.

Comment: If the fruit isn't there, you cant try and get it here: `fruitPrices[fruit]`, so don't you need to put in a `continue` or `else`

Comment: I was just writing out your `sum` line.  The case of missing fruit (if they can just be skipped, anyhow) can be dealt with concisely too: `sum(fruitPrices.get(fruit, 0) * n for fruit, n in orderList)`

Comment: It makes a lot more sense when I step through your logic. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Could get this down to one line, but I dont think it will help.  You are looping over the prices dictionary, but should be looping over the orderList, and then looking up the fruit in the dictionary.

```
def buyLotsOfFruit(orderList):
    totalCost = 0.0 
    for fruit, quantity in orderList:
       if fruit not in fruitPrices:
           print 'not here!'
       else:
           totalCost = totalCost +fruitPrices[fruit]* quantiy            
    return totalCost
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruitPrices = {'apples':2.00, 'oranges': 1.50, 'pears': 1.75,'limes':0.75,   
               'strawberries':1.00}

def buyLotsOfFruit(orderList):
    ##    orderList: List of (fruit, numPounds) tuples        
    ## Returns cost of order

    totalCost = 0.0 
    for fruit,price in fruitPrices.items():
        if fruit not in fruitPrices:
            print 'not here!'
        else:
            #totalCost = totalCost +fruitPrices[fruitPrices.index(fruit)].key() * price            
            totalCost = totalCost +fruitPrices[fruit] * price

    return totalCost
```

Answer (score 0):

## **NOTE**:

You can put this entire function into a one-liner like this:

```
buyLotsOfFruit = lambda ol: sum(fruitPrices[f] * p for f, p in ol if f in fruitPrices)
```

Or this other way:

```
def buyLotsOfFruit(orderList):
    ##    orderList: List of (fruit, numPounds) tuples        
    ## Returns cost of order

    totalCost = 0.0 
    for fruit, pounds in orderList:
        if fruit not in fruitPrices:
            print 'not here!'
        else:
            totalCost += fruitPrices[fruit] * pounds
    return totalCost
```

To retrieve a key from a dictionary all you need is this: `dictionary[key]`
and it returns the value